# Janela Modal ao clicar em link de info box aberta por um marcador do Google Maps

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, marcadores

Estou utilizando o Bootstrap e na minha pagina *index*, tenho umas janelas modais funcionando, que abrem quando eu clico em um `href`.

Tenho também uma div para o mapa que lê um arquivo JSON, onde, existem as informações para adicionar os marcadores nele, são elas: ID, latitude, longitude e um conteúdo para uma "infobox" que vai abrir ao clicar no marcador.

O problema é que nesse conteúdo da infobox tenho um:

```
<a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">Veja mais</a>
```

Do mesmo modo que eu faço para abrir a janela modal por outros "a hrefs" na minha página, porém, este link acima que é exibido na infobox do marcador não abre a janela modal. A URL muda para `http://www.meusite.com/index.html#portfolioModal1`

PS: Era como se na infobox fosse uma sinopse e ao clicar em Veja mais abriria todas as informações do local... porém nada acontece. Alguma ideia?

Caso achem necessário colocar trechos de código me avisem que eu coloco, achei que não era necessário pois quem conhece as ferramentas mencionadas sabe como funcionam.

Obrigado!

Comment: Como está o id ou name da div do seu modal? Tem que estar com portfolioModal1 também.

Comment: Sim, está tudo certinho, tanto que fora desse "infobox" do marcador, funciona, qualquer link igual o acima abre a janela

Comment: Oi, Bruno, escrever de mais nunca é legal para o entendimento do problema, mas não conte com *"quem conhece as ferramentas mencionadas sabe como funcionam"*, tem vezes que não sei a resposta e tento resolver só pelo desafio. Anyway, confira o guia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), vale bem à pena. E se souber Inglês, o guia do Jon Skeet é tipo definitivo, bom mesmo, upgrade instantâneo nas nossas capacidades de explicar um problema: [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Ola brasofilo, eu disse isso pois não convém colar o código do bootstrap aqui, achei que o problema ficou intendivel, só gostaria de um caminho, o que seria possivel estar causando o problema, só queria que as funcoes responsaveis pelo modal abrir tivessem efeito dentro da infobox.... De qualquer forma obrigado pelo seu comentario, vou me atentar às dicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui aqui. Ao invés de utilizar os métodos prontos do bootstrap para abrir o modal pela infobox, na minha infobox fiz um `<a href="#" onclick="mostrar()">Veja mais</a>`

E então, no meu index.html fiz uma funcao js `mostrar()`

```
        $('#portfolioModal' + id).modal('toggle');
        $('#portfolioModal' + id).modal('show');
```

Deu certinho, meu unico problema é que a pagina sobe (vai ao topo) não permanece aonde estava...